# Select Result from MySQL Database and Assign it to a Variable

Tags: python, mysql

I am connecting to a MySQL database through a Python environment. I'm using pypyodbc as the connector. Everything works fine, I can Select and Insert results, etc.

The issue comes in when I attempt to actually assign results fetched from the database to a variable: It literally only works sometimes, and rarely.

Here's some code:

```
SQLCommand = ("SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM ColumnName) FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable WHERE ColumnName='%s'" % (my_variable)
cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
print("Here is the result from the database ",  cursor.fetchone())

another_variable =  cursor.fetchone()
print("Here is the value from the database assigned to a variable: ", another_variable)
```

As you can see I attempt to assign the fetched result to a variable at:

```
another_variable =  cursor.fetchone()
```

The word I'm fetching will be in the database plain as day. Cursor.fetchone will fetch the result and print it every time. But it will only assign it to a variable sometimes. Rarely.

I'm baffled, is there some known issue doing this? Am I somehow missing anything? I need it to assign the result to the cursor everytime, not rarely.

Comment: When you call `cursor.fetchone()` a second time it will attempt to fetch a second row. Do you have multiple rows that satisfy the condition?

Comment: I only call fetchone once. I was just highlighting the space again where I'm trying to assign it to a variable. Is that what you mean? I'll check if multiple rows satisfy the condition though thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be assigning an alias to your call to `TRIM` inside the query, e.g.

```
SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM ColumnName) AS val FROM MyAI_DB.dbo.MyDatabase ...
```

Then, to access a column/alias, you need to reference the `row` object returned by `fetchone()`:

```
sql = "SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM ColumnName) AS val FROM MyAI_DB.dbo.MyDatabase " +
    "WHERE ColumnName = '%s'" % (my_variable)
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print print "%s" % (row["val"])
```